# Alternatives to TrueCrypt in compliance with Fedora 15 guidelines

Tags: fedora, truecrypt

Due to licensing issues TrueCrypt is not included in Fedora 15 (source [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/ForbiddenItems#TrueCrypt)). Although not address by Fedora itself there's also concerns regarding the developers identities and related issues (source [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt#Developers.2FOwners_identities_and_related_concerns)). I'm looking for possible alternatives that matches the following requisites:

- Compliance with Fedora licensing guidelines
- Able to encrypt a partition
- Allows me to mount the encrypted partition both on Windows and Linux (I'm using a dual boot system)
- Peer reviewed by the cryptography community

Is there any package that meet those guidelines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[LUKS](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Implementing_LUKS_Disk_Encryption) (a.k.a. [cryptsetup](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/)) is the standard for Linux disk encryption. It can encrypt a whole encryption, or a set of partitions through [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29).

With [FreeOTFE](http://freeotfe.org/), you can also access LUKS encrypted volumes under Windows. From the [cryptsetup homepage](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/):

> LUKS is also cross-platform standard. Thanks to FreeOTFE, you get LUKS for Win32. Of course, you have to use a file-system on your LUKS partition that both OS understand to actually make use of this cross-platform capability (either use ext2fs drivers for windows or use FAT drivers for Linux).

`cryptsetup` is [licensed under GPLv2](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/) and according to this [Licensing article](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing), it is compliant with the Fedora licensing guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

Fedora itself has a started a fork called [RealCrypt](http://rpmfusion.org/Package/realcrypt).

Otherwise, [Diskcryptor](http://www.diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page/en).

Answer (score 1):

[ecryptfs](https://launchpad.net/ecryptfs) has some advantages over LUKS like dynamic size of the encrypted tree.